# nextjs Image property null

Tags: next.js

I have a component with dynamic content like so :
`<Image width="680" height="400" src={post.imgsrc} alt={post.title} />`

I keep having the same error even if I have added the width/height :

> Image with src "/imgs/paintings/2022/2.jpg" must use "width" and "height" properties or "layout='fill'" property.

I don't know why, and I wonder why I have to specify width and height since my pictures have different sizes...

Comment: You need to provide numeric values: `<Image width={680} height={400} ...`. And the reason for requiring them is to prevent [cumulative layout shift](https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/web-performance/cls).

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't know about this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to mention is that you can import the images if they are local, if you want that you do not need to use width, height, or fill.
They get provided automatically

Example from the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images):

```
import profilePic from '../public/me.png'

import Image from 'next/image'
import profilePic from '../public/me.png'

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>My Homepage</h1>
      <Image
        src={profilePic}
        alt="Picture of the author"
        // width={500} automatically provided
        // height={500} automatically provided
        // blurDataURL="data:..." automatically provided
        // placeholder="blur" // Optional blur-up while loading
      />
      <p>Welcome to my homepage!</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

[This](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#remote-images) also explains why remote images do need these properties.

Comment: Thank you very much, I get it now, I used the import method and it's working.